# Maintaining value of a variable through many pages in PHP WITHOUT COOKIES,SESSIONS

Tags: php, variables

I am having problem in maintaing value of variable through several pages(actually through same page but through many refresh).
The first time I get navigated to new page the value of variable is preserved and can be used by echo,but after refreshing the page that value cannot be reused,it shows error that the variable has no value.
I am making a webapp for chatting in php.
I want to show the name of user(sender) on every page(every page of sending message). So I am using code

```
<?php 
$writtervar = $_POST['writter'];
echo $writtervar;
?>
```

I am taking input through a separate page,code is

```
<form action="ddd.php" method="post">
     Enter your name   <input type="text" name="writter" >
     <input type="submit"  id="submit" value="Press" >
</form>
```

Comment: Use `session`s.

Comment: Finding out some way without cookies,sessions....

Comment: Well then add more details to your question. You must have something in mind..

Comment: I just want the my code to be understandable to the beginner who doesn't know concept of cookies.So I want to make it as simple as possible.

Comment: Put a link to the manual in the comments, other ways are going to be more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP is stateless. `$_POST` array is populated when a user makes a request. If you want to have access to a value accross web views, read on [setcookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) or [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php).

If you don't want to use cookies, you'll need to resend your parameters on every request (probably obscured some way). Or send an identifier on every request an keep your info server (you can do that with php sessions anyway). But doing that is not convenient nor secure.

Comment: Finding out some way without cookies

Answer (score 1):

You can use **session**. base on your code you can try this:
In start page (ddd.php) you have to set your session values.

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $_SESSION["writer"] = $_POST["writter"];
?>
...
```

in other page use your session values as e.g:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  ...
  echo $_SESSION["writer"];
?>
```

Note that **unset** and **destroy** your session at the end off your work.

```
<?php
    // remove all session variables
    session_unset();

    // destroy the session
    session_destroy(); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a cookie

```
$value = 'something from somewhere';
setcookie("TestCookie", $value);
```

and get the value:

```
echo $_COOKIE["TestCookie"];
```

You can also use sessions:

```
session_start();

// Set session variables
$_SESSION["TestSession"] = $value;

// Get session
echo $_SESSION["TestSession"];
```

You'd better use a framework like [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) that can help you handle sessions, forms, redirect with values etc.

You can find the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) on php.net

Comment: Finding out some way without cookies